# Get the Id of a Layout from its name

Tags: apex, api, tooling-api

Im looking to use a combination of the tooling api object ProfileLayout and the SetupAuditTrail object. I can query the SetupAuditTrail and with a bit of parsing extract the names of any layouts that have changed, i then want to use this info in combination with ProfileLayout, however, this only contains the IDs of the Layouts.

So the Q is, is there any way to get the Id of a layout using the layouts name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a Tooling API query for the Id:

```
SELECT Id FROM Layout WHERE Name = 'Account Layout'
```

> GET /services/data/v44.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Layout+WHERE+Name+=Account+Layout'

You can query other information this way too (see the Tooling API [Layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_layout.htm) object), but note that values like `FullName` and `Metadata` can only be retrieved if the result set contains exactly one record.

You'll probably want to query for `Id` first, based on the `Name`, to determine if there are any duplicates at the Name level, and then descend with single-record queries to finer detail.